# Make Visual Studio Code Debug Console colors match Unreal Engine C++ Error/Warning Syntax

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio-code, unreal-engine4, vscode-debugger

I'm using VSCode with Unreal Engine ad I was wondering if there was a way to change the default Debug Console colors.

The main problem with VSCode console is that everything is blue, Errors and Warnings are not clearly distinguishable and I'd like to be able to change them.

I looked for an extension for days but with no results, the only thing I found is [an extension for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MikeWard-AnnArbor.VSColorOutput64) (not VSCode) that allows you to change the console output using regex (That would be fine for me, I use regex a lot and I could use it to even detect more colors using different patterns in the log message).

It would be enough for me to change the default blue to white/yellow/red, but if you have a regex solution that would be awesome!

Thank you in advance and have a nice day!

Unreal Engine Output Log:
[image]

VSCode Debug Console:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Debug Console supports ANSI Escape Sequences.

For a JavaScript program:

```js
console.log("\x1b[35mSome text in magenta.\x1b[0m Back to normal terminal color");
```

Modify the print statements to add the wanted color codes

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's a good solution but it requires to change every single debug print and it's not supported in the Unreal output log (and I'm the only one using unreal from visual studio in the team so it could be a problem for others).

Comment: @Ares9323 Define color strings based on some command line argument or environment setting, so if not defined all these strings are the empty string